# layout displayed on emulator but not completely displayed on phone

Tags: android, layout

I have a nested linear layout. On my emulator, the complete layout is visible. But on my phone, the layout is not completely displayed. It gets cut in between. It does not show the bottom most elements.

How do I make the layout fit completely into my screen?

screenshot of how it looks on my phone:

[image: screenshot of how it looks on my phone:]

Here is my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@raw/bg1"    
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"       
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"       
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />    

    </LinearLayout>

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"        
        android:text="Button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:background="#33FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"   />

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"       
        android:src="@drawable/ic_talk" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think it is ambiguous what you are saying, and you should provide some screenshots.

Comment: Is your emulator width and height is same as your phone ?

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu  i've updated the question. please check.

Comment: If your mobile screen size is lesser then your emulater screen then you could not see full layout. To fix this issue use [scrollview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Comment: @kTekkie No, i dont think so. But even if i adjust my emulator width and height as per my phone, when i run it on other phones, it'll create the same problem right?

Comment: @Gunaseelan Thanks.. I could use that as an alternative. But isn't there any way in which the layout adjusts its size according to the device screen?

Comment: @newbee Yes, It is depends on your layout's height. Not on your emulater's height. sorry for my previous comment. To fix your problem you can use scrollview.

Comment: @newbee To see about device comfortably see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work with weights you will get the same result regardless of the screensize. Which I think is your problem in this case.
It is explained on this page:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

For example:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is beacuse you are declaring the widths, heights and boarders of the elements as a static number. Your device and emulator must be different sizes and you have hard coded values that make it display properly on the emulator but not on any other device. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) to learn out how to properly make a layout.

Comment: According to the link that you have given, it says `In general, specifying a layout width and height using absolute units such as pixels is not recommended. Instead, using relative measurements such as density-independent pixel units (dp), wrap_content, or fill_parent, is a better approach, because it helps ensure that your application will display properly across a variety of device screen sizes. The accepted measurement types are defined in the Available Resources document.`   And since i have used **dp** in all my hard coded values it should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: apologies I missed that in your code. Is the bottom of the view missing from the screen is it? If so you will need to use a scroll view so that you can scroll the rest of the items onto the page.